# bundlel.js page not found in react App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

bundle.js page not found error, and i add the script tag to the index.html file.
In the webpack.config.js file, set the output path as

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**AppContainer.jsx**

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
 'use strict';
     const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "app.jsx"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["env", "react"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/"),
        compress: true
    },
    devtool: "source-map"
};
```

**App.jsx**

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';

import AppContainer from './AppContainer.jsx';

render(<AppContainer/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

this is the my react repository link : [react link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5f4du3qbmui1psr/AACkCAxtIl14lCv7brtGsq3Pa?dl=0)

Comment: Where does your `index.html` file live? The `bundle.js` src should be relative to where it exists. So if they are both in `dist`, change your src to `./bundle.js`. If not, then you'll need to go to `/dist` first and reference it there.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but maybe you can give a shot to [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)? It will automatically generate HTML for you and properly link your bundle in a script.

run `npm i --save-dev html-webpack-plugin`, and set:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "app.jsx"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/'  // not sure if that will make any difference though
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["env", "react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/"),
    compress: true
  },
  devtool: "source-map"
};
```